# How to convert text (cell) into ascii code? (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, text, ascii

Is there a way in matlab to convert a text (type is cell) into ascii code? All the ways i googled did not work like double (text.txt). An error occurs "cell cant be converted to double". I can use a converter outside of matlab, but is it possible to convert it in the programm? Text is 380 words.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to accomplish. It would clarify your question a lot, I believe, if you added an example input and output.

Answer (score 0):

To access the *contents* of a cell array, even if it only has one element, you have to index it using **curly brackets**. Round brackets give you another cell array.

```
>> mytext = {'foo', 'bar'}
mytext =
  1×2 cell array
    'foo'    'bar'

>> mytext(1)
ans =
  cell
    'foo'

>> mytext{1}
ans =
foo
```

If I understand correctly, you have a cell array (even if it's only 1 x 1) containing a character vector, and you want to convert the character vector into a vector of doubles:

```
>> double(mytext{1})
ans =
   102   111   111
```

If that isn't the answer to your problem, please edit your question with more detail about what you're trying to do, showing your code and any error messages you get.